# Convergence of a complex series $S = \sum_{p\, prime}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{p^{-ks}}{k}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to figure out why the series

$$S = \sum_{p\, prime}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{p^{-ks}}{k}$$

converges, for any $s \in \mathbb{C}$ with Re$(s) > 1$.

The main difficulty here is the double sum. I can show that an inner series converges, but then I end up with an infinite series from the outer sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It converges for $\Re(s) > 1$ because it is $\le \sum_{p,k} |p^{-ks}|\le \sum_n |n^{-s}|$,

it converges for $\Re(s) > 1/2$ because it is $$\le \sum_{p,k} |p^{-2ks}|+\sum_{p,k} |p^{-(2k+1)s}|\le 2 \sum_{p,k} |p^{-2ks}|\le 2 \sum_n |n^{-2s}|$$